# BottomNavigationView does not work with Samsung Galaxy SM-T113

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview

I am building app that need to run on specific device, Samsung Galaxy SM-T113.
my problem is that i get this: android.view.InflateException.

The strange thing is when i run it on my Xiomi mi 5, it runs perfect.

I have seen some posts here but nothing helped me so far.

Iam working on SDK ver: 27 all my gredal:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
```

my Logcat is this:

```
04-13 18:40:08.762 11599-11599/com.actionbar E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.actionbar, PID: 11599
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.actionbar/com.actionbar.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #74: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2429)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2493)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:166)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1283)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5584)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #74: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:627)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:703)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:762)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:771)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:771)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:499)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
at com.actionbar.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:189)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5447)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2393)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2493) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:166) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1283) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5584) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084) 
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                                                            Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:601)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:703) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:762) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:771) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:771) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:499) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354) 
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287) 

at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139).
at com.actionbar.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:189) 
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5447) 
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2393) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2493) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:166) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1283) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5584) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084) 
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f020075 a=-1 r=0x7f020075}
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3423)
at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:614)
at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3585)
at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:470)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.<init>(FrameLayout.java:101)
at android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView.<init>(BottomNavigationView.java:118)
at android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView.<init>(BottomNavigationView.java:114)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:601) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:703) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:762) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:771) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:771) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:499) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354) 
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287) 
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
at com.actionbar.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:189) 
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5447) 
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2393) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2493) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:166) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1283) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5584) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084) 
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

My XML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.actionbar.MainActivity">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/relLayout">


    <!--************************-->
    <!-- Top Part of the Screen -->
    <!--************************-->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/relLayoutTopBar"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">


        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/white_grey_border_bottom">

            </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>


    <!--***************************-->
    <!-- Middle Part of the Screen -->
    <!--***************************-->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/relLayoutMiddle"
        android:layout_below="@+id/relLayoutTopBar"
        android:layout_above="@+id/relLayoutBotBar">

        <!--<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager-->
        <!--</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>-->
        <com.actionbar.CustomViewPager
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        </com.actionbar.CustomViewPager>

    </RelativeLayout>




    <!--***************************-->
    <!-- Buttom Part of the Screen -->
    <!--***************************-->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/relLayoutBotBar"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/bottomNavView_Bar"
            android:background="@drawable/white_grey_border_top"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_menu">
        </android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView>
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

My Menu Xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item
android:id="@+id/ic_email"
android:icon="@drawable/ic_email"
android:title="Email"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/ic_pen1"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_pen"
    android:title="Pen 1"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/ic_pen2"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_pen"
    android:title="Pen 2"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/ic_settings"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings"
    android:title="Settings"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/ic_ink"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_ink"
    android:title="Ink"/>
</menu>
```